# Remapping `numpy.array` with missing values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm dealing with some large data sets - observations as a function of time - which are not continuous in time (i.e., there is a lot of missing data, where the complete record is absent). To make things fun, there are a lot of data sets, all with missing records, all at random places...

I somehow need to get the data "synchronised" in time, with missing data flagged as missing data, instead of being completely absent. I've managed to get this partially working, but I'm still having some problems.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

# The date range (in the format that I'm dealing with), which I define
# myself for the period in which I'm interested
dc = np.arange(2010010100, 2010010106)

# Observation dates (d1) and values (v1)
d1  = np.array([2010010100, 2010010104, 2010010105]) # date
v1  = np.array([10,         11,         12        ]) # values

# Another data set with (partially) other times
d2  = np.array([2010010100, 2010010102, 2010010104]) # date
v2  = np.array([13,         14,         15        ]) # values

# For now set -1 as fill_value
v1_filled = -1 * np.ones_like(dc)
v2_filled = -1 * np.ones_like(dc)

v1_filled[dc.searchsorted(d1)] = v1
v2_filled[dc.searchsorted(d2)] = v2
```

This gives me the desired result:

```
v1_filled = [10 -1 -1 -1 11 12]
v2_filled = [13 -1 14 -1 15 -1]
```

but only if the values in `d1` or `d2` are also in `dc`; if a value in `d1` or `d2` is not in `dc` the code fails because then `searchsorted` behaves as:

> If there is no suitable index, return either 0 or N (where N is the length of `a`).

So for example, if I change `d2` and `v2` to:

```
d2  = np.array([2010010100, 2010010102, 2010010104, 0]) # date
v2  = np.array([13,         14,         15,         9999]) # values
```

The result is

```
[9999   -1   14   -1   15   -1]
```

In this case, because `d2=0` is not in `dc`, it should discard that value, instead of inserting it at the start (or end). Any idea how to easily achieve that?

Comment: This kind of task is exactly what pandas is great for.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that.. I have a bit of a love-hate relationship with Pandas; it seems to be very useful, but I also find it a bit difficult to get started with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `d2 = np.intersect1d(dc, d2)` before calling `dc.searchsorted(d2)` it will remove all elements in d2 that are not in dc.

Comment: I ended up using a slightly different approach (compressing the masked arrays first to remove the masked values, since not all statistics routines work well with masked arrays), but `intersect1d()` was indeed the missing step...